# Finding the $y$- intercept to a tangent

Tags: algebra-precalculus, tangent-line

I've tried to solve this problem, but I am having some problems.

I need to find the $y$- intercept of the tangent to $y = \frac{18}{x^2+2}$
at point $(1,6)$.

I keep getting $0$, but I don't think that's right.

Comment: Step 1: What is the tangent line?

Comment: That would be (-36x)/((x^2 + 2)^2), right?

Comment: No, that isn't a line.  A line should be linear in $x$ (no powers, no $x$'s in the denominator).

Comment: then it would be -4?

Comment: I assume you know calculus? Then differentiate $\frac{18}{x^2+2}$ and plug in $x = 1$ to get a value for the gradient. Then use $y-y_1=m(x-x_1)$ to find the equation of the line.

Comment: $-4$ is the *slope* of the tangent line, it isn't a line.  A line should be of the form $y=mx+b$.

Comment: I think you got the $x$-intercept as $0$, which is perfectly right except you needed to find the $y$-intercept which is $10$.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: Compute the tangent line.

- The tangent line is a line passing through the point $(1,6)$ with the same slope as the curve that that point.
- In order to write down a line, you need a point on the line and the slope of the line.  You already have a point, but you need to find the slope of the line.
- The slope of the line is the derivative at the point $(1,6)$, since the function is 
  $$
  \frac{18}{x^2+2},
  $$
  its derivative is 
  $$
  -\frac{36x}{(x^2+2)^2}
  $$
  plugging in $x=1$ from the point $(1,6)$, we get that the slope is
  $$
  -\frac{36}{3^2}=-4.
  $$
  This is the slope of the line of interest.
- Therefore, using the point-slope form of a line, you get that the tangent line is $y-6=(-4)(x-1)$.

Step 2: Find the $y$-intercept.

- You have the point-slope form of a line, to get $y-6=-4(x-1)$.  We can turn this into slope-intercept form to get $y=-4x+10$.
- Therefore, your $y$-intercept is $10$.

Answer (score 0):

First you find the slope of tangent line at the point of tangency. Slope of tangent line is derivative of the function evaluated at the point of tangency. For $y=18/(x^2+2)$ we use quotient rule to get $y'=-36x/(x^2+2)^2$.$m=y'(1) =-4$ is the slope and y=6-4(x-1) is the equation of the tangent line. To find the y intercept we let $x=0$ and get $y=10.$ Thus the point $(0,10)$ is the $y$ intercept of the tangent line.